Approximating asymptotically the Laplace inverse of $\frac{\exp\left(-\sqrt{s^2 + 1}\right)}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}}$ for larger t
I was trying to find the behavior of the inverse laplace transform of the function $$F(s)=\frac{\exp\left(-\sqrt{s^2 + 1}\right)}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}}$$ for larger $t$.
So basically here is my approach: I need to evaluate $I =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{\exp\left(-\sqrt{s^2 + 1}\right)}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}} e^{st} \, ds$.
The branch points for the function is at $s=\pm i$ and we shall focus on the branch point $s=i$.
Since the dominant contribution is from the branch points, we could use the substitution $s=i+i\delta$, which finally gives the expression,
$$I=e^{i t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\, \frac{e^{i(\delta t- \sqrt{2 \delta})}}{\sqrt{\delta}}\, d\delta$$
Further substitution of $\sqrt{\delta}=u$ and the saddle point approximation, we get the final answer as:
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \cos\left(t-\frac{1}{2 t}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$
Here is my question:
The exact Laplace inverse of this function is supposed to be the Bessel function $J_0\left(\sqrt{t^2-1}\right) H\left(t-1\right)$ which for larger $t$ has the value
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}} \cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
This clearly doesnot match with my answer with a difference in the sign of $\frac{\pi}{4}.$
Can anybody please point out to me as to where I am going wrong? Or whether I have obtained the right answer?

Starting from
$$I=e^{i t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\, \frac{e^{i(\delta t- \sqrt{2 \delta})}}{\sqrt{\delta}}\, d\delta$$
$$I=\frac{(1+i) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{\sqrt{t}}\, e^{i t-\frac{i}{2 t}}\, A$$ where
$$A=1+(1-i)\, C\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t } }\right)+(1+i)\, S\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}  }\right)$$ where $C(.)$ and $S(.)$ are Fresnel integrals.
Using asymptotics
$$I \sim\left((1+i) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2t}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t}+\frac{i}{3 \sqrt{2}
   t^2}\right) \exp \left(i \left(t-\frac{1}{2 t}\right)\right)$$
Trying to $t=100$ and converting to decimals, the above approximation gives$0.183931 + 0.0365522 \,i$ to compared to $\cdots$ the same.
Edit
Expanding the $A$ term only
$$A=1+\frac{(1-i)  }{\sqrt{\pi }\,t^{1/2}}+\frac 16\frac{(1+i)  }{\sqrt{\pi }\,t^{3/2}}-\frac 1{40} \frac{(1-i)  }{\sqrt{\pi }\,t^{5/2}}-\frac 1{336} \frac{(1+i)  }{\sqrt{\pi }\,t^{7/2}}+\cdots$$

So, does this mean that the answer I obtained is correct? I could see that your solution matches mine but not the asymptotic form of Bessel functions.

@MB17. You are very correct.
